# Spring data + JPA - locking occurs even though no @Lock was set

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, deadlock

We are developing a web app using spring data + JPA and mySQL.

On the beginning of our development process we considered AVOIDING using @Lock all together for the sake of avoiding Deadlocks.

Today one of our automated tests actually generated a deadlock exception.

Our questions

1) How come we have a deadlock even without setting @Lock on our repositories?

2) If deadlocks are unavoidable - we read that consistent locking order can mitigate the deadlock issues, how can we manipulate our repositories (that mostly do HQL \ SQL updates) that the lock order will be consistent?

Comment: *How come we have a deadlock even without setting @Lock on our repositories?*  did you make a thread dump to see what's going on ?

Comment: Could you show us please what is exactly doing the test that generates a deadlock exception?